# How do I replace double quotes with single quotes

Tags: php, regex, quotes

How can I replace `""` (I think it's called double quotes) with `''` (I think its called single quotes) using PHP?

Comment: Lets say you had `"Testing"` - you want `'Testing'` - and vice-versa?  What about `"They're"` - you want `'They"re'` ??

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
str_replace('"', "'", $text);
```

or Re-assign it

```
$text = str_replace('"', "'", $text);
```

Comment: Yes this is right, but just a newb comment from me. This won't actually change the value of $text by itself, you'll need to set the whole thing equal to $text like this: `$text = str_replace('"',"'",$text);` Just had to mention this, because I just made this mistake

Comment: @SSHThis I did that one time. Took me an hour to figure out what went wrong. Def a newb mistake!

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
$str = str_replace('"','\'',$str)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with preg_replace,

```
<?php
$string="hello \" sdfsd \" dgf";
echo $string,"\n";
echo preg_replace("/\"/","'",$string);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use str_replace, try to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php it contains allot of php documentation.

```
<?php

echo str_replace("\"","'","\"\"\"\"\" hello world\n");
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with strtr,

```
<?php
$string="hello \" sdfsd dgf";
echo $string;
$string = strtr($string, "\"", "'");
echo $string;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

For PHP 5.3.7

```
$str = str_replace('&quot;','&#39;',$str);
```

OR

```
$str = str_replace('&quot;',"'",$str);
```

For PHP 5.2

```
$str = str_replace('"',"'",$str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//single qoutes
$content = str_replace("\'", "'", $content); 

//double qoutes
$content = str_replace('\"', '"', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use an intermediate variable:

```
$OutText = str_replace('"',"'",$InText);
```

Also, you should have a Test.php file where you can try stuff out:

```
$QText = 'I "am" quoted';
echo "<P>QText is: $QText";
$UnQText = str_replace ('"', '', $QText);
echo "<P>Unquoted is: $UnQText";
```

z