# Replace double quote in single quote

Tags: php, quote

If I use a double quote in title of my application i have a problem , then I want to create a condition :

if i have double quote , use single quote .

Thanks you very much !

Comment: use replace function

Comment: show us some code sample what you tried

Comment: `str_replace('"', "'", $text);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace double quotes with single quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424281/how-do-i-replace-double-quotes-with-single-quotes)

Comment: `str_replace('"',"'",$str);`

Comment: `If I use a double quote in title of my application i have a problem`.... what is the problem? Address the problem, not simply to to find a workround!

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking. Please add an example string, the expected output, the output you are currently having and example code.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided much context for your question so it's difficult to know exactly how to help, but lets say you have a variable called `$title` with double quotes in it, you can replace them like this:

`$title = str_replace('"', "'", $title);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str_replace()` following :

```
str_replace('"', "'", $text);
```

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)