# Replace double quotes by simple using json_encode

Tags: php, json

I have an array :

```
['One', 'Two',...]
```

And when i use json_enconde on this array, it returns to me this :

```
["One", "Two",...]
```

I need to pass this array to a JS function and to success I must pass an array like the first one, only with simple quotes. However json_encode returns the array with double quotes.

Is there any solution to replace in the json_encode(myArray) double quotes by simple quotes ?

When I use

```
[\'One\',\'Two\',...]
```

it works my JS function returns an array, only with this way. So i need to pass something like that.

I have something like

```
echo '<div onclick="generateUP(\'john\','.json_encode($myArray).',\'smith\')"></div>';
```

It doesn't work but

```
echo '<div onclick="generateUP(\'john\',[\'One\',\'Two\'],\'smith\')"></div>';
```

works great...

Thanks

Comment: There is no real difference between those 2 arrays. NOTE: JSON stipulates that it will expect double quotes around text and field names.

Comment: PS: The first single quote you have in example one is not a valid single quote! Use a text editor and not a document editor(word) to write your code

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424281/how-do-i-replace-double-quotes-with-single-quotes

Comment: I edited my post, see my problem quotes are not a part of my values in my array, quotes are a problem generated by json_encode

Comment: what is `generateUP` function??
and you are putting json array in as a parameter for that function?

what you can do is you can use `JSON.parse()` in javascript when passing to function..

Comment: what is `\'john\'` and `\'smith\'` in parameters. clearly they are not json???

Comment: john and smith are just some string parameters, generateUP function is a Jquery function using ajax. Like i wrote it's the only way to pass the array, if i use another way JS returns me illegal string argument, or } expected

Answer (score 0):

what if you do like this

assign that to a javascript variable and send variable in that function as a parameter??

```
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 var data = JSON.parse('<?=json_encode($myArray)?>');
</script>
<?php
echo '<div onclick="generateUP(\'john\',data ,\'smith\')"></div>';
```

Comment: I tried JSON.parse('.json_encode($this->_myArray).') cuz i'm working in a PHP class so i can't use what you said, and it returns SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Comment: this is why i used ?> before starting html tags.
you don't need to write it in php.. only dot the process in php. echo it inside the JSON.parser function.