# to remove or replace double quotes in php in mysql query

Tags: php

I need to remove all double quotes,single quotes from string in php mysql query, so i will use `REPLACE()` in query but no any changes or result.

QUERY BELOW:

```
$strSql = "select RW.review_channelid,RW.review_id,RW.create_date,RW.rating_overall,RW.isold,RW.guestreplysent,RW.guest_id,RW.guest_name,REPLACE(RW.review_title,'\"','') as review_title,RW.channel_id,RW.review_type,RW.review_method,RW.your_view,RW.neg_review,CH.extranet_url,RW.checkout_date,RW.review_time,CH.channel_code,CH.channel_name,RW.isposted_facebook,RW.isposted_twitter,IF(RW.review_time ='0000-00-00',create_date,review_time) AS rtime
                       from ".dbtable::ReviewMaster." AS RW
                       left join ".dbtable::ChannelMaster." AS CH ON RW.channel_id = CH.channel_id
                       where prop_code = '".$_SESSION['AdminDetails']['prop_code']."' ";
```

i want to replace or remove double,single quotes in middle of  string in PHP  `REPLACE(RW.review_title,'\"','')` for review_title in mysql query

Any body having any idea please help to sort it out. Thanks

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424281/how-do-i-replace-double-quotes-with-single-quotes

Comment: Please instead look into prepared statements and bind variables!

Comment: Is this to normalize the text for some processor, or to prevent SQL injections?

Comment: You should have a look at proper quoting, and not at simple replacements. But to know how to do this, we need to know more about your setup - are you using PHP, MySQL workbench, **or** some Qt library? This is mutually exclusive

Comment: im using php mysql @NicoHaase

Comment: And what have you tried so far? If you want to replace something in a string that is inputted through PHP, then run that replacement in PHP and use the properly quoted string for your query. If you want to use data from the database, also do the replacement in PHP after querying your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace(replace(RW.review_title,'"',""),''',"")



> $strSql = "select
> RW.review_channelid,RW.review_id,RW.create_date,RW.rating_overall,RW.isold,RW.guestreplysent,RW.guest_id,RW.guest_name,replace(replace(RW.review_title,'"',""),''',""),'\"','')
> as
> review_title,RW.channel_id,RW.review_type,RW.review_method,RW.your_view,RW.neg_review,CH.extranet_url,RW.checkout_date,RW.review_time,CH.channel_code,CH.channel_name,RW.isposted_facebook,RW.isposted_twitter,IF(RW.review_time
> ='0000-00-00',create_date,review_time) AS rtime
>                        from ".dbtable::ReviewMaster." AS RW
>                        left join ".dbtable::ChannelMaster." AS CH ON RW.channel_id = CH.channel_id
>                        where prop_code = '".$_SESSION['AdminDetails']['prop_code']."' ";
```

Comment: It give error `
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in`  @nageen nayak

Answer (score 0):

```
$strSql = "select RW.review_channelid,RW.review_id,RW.create_date,RW.rating_overall,RW.isold,RW.guestreplysent,RW.guest_id,RW.guest_name,REPLACE(RW.review_title,'&quot;','') as review_title,RW.channel_id,RW.review_type,RW.review_method,REPLACE(RW.your_view,'&quot;','') as your_view,REPLACE(RW.neg_review,'&quot;','') as neg_review,CH.extranet_url,RW.checkout_date,RW.review_time,CH.channel_code,CH.channel_name,RW.isposted_facebook,RW.isposted_twitter,IF(RW.review_time ='0000-00-00',create_date,review_time) AS rtime
                       from ".dbtable::ReviewMaster." AS RW
                       left join ".dbtable::ChannelMaster." AS CH ON RW.channel_id = CH.channel_id
                       where prop_code = '".$_SESSION['AdminDetails']['prop_code']."' ";
```